# Imageview isn't updating after fetching an image from a server with Alamofireimage

Tags: swift, xcode, ios8, alamofire, alamofireimage

I've been working on a project that needs to display an image fetched from a server using AlamofireImage. So my code goes like this:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView

func downloadImage() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.axs.gt/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/tuzonapromo_600x.png").responseImage { (response) -> Void  in
        if let image = response.result.value {
               imageView.image = image
        }
}
```

It seems like the image is being downloaded but the imageView is not updating the new image fetched from the server. I must add that I'm able to download from HTTP and HTTPS since all the securities implications have been solved.

I also tried to do this

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "someImage")
```

And the imageView still doesn't update.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried to put this if let inside a dispatch_async block?

Comment: I have already done that since I read that everything in the view that needs to be updated must be on the main thread, but still didn't work.

Comment: These completion blocks are on main thread. You should check to see if `response` was `.Success` or `.Failure`. Do you know if the request is succeeding? But if `imageView.image = UIImage(named: ...)` isn't working, then that suggests a deeper problem with your imageview (e.g. have to you looked at the frame and made sure it's visible? this isn't in a table view cell, is it?). As an aside, is there some reason you don't just `imageView.af_setImageWithURL(URL)`? And if doing this in cell of table or collection view, consider using placeholder image, too.

Comment: I've been debugging the application and I can confirm that the `response` is `.Success`. And `imgView.image = image` is being executed. My imageView has a default image so I'm sure it is visible. And I've tried to use imageView.af_setImageWithUrl(URL) but no success, and I'm not really sure about how that works. It is an UIImageVie and not a table view cell or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was verifying the flow of my code and came to realization that I was trying to update my imageViews's image before the viewDidLoad method, which calls the `super.viewDidLoad()` method, which is supposed to initialize everything in my View (aka setting the default image for my imageView). So what was actually happening was that I was fetching the image way before the compiler set the default image.

Thanks for the help.